# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException while updating Geoserver WFS using QGIS 2.16.3

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs, error

I get the following error when I try to update features using a WFS in QGIS 2.16.3 version (NOTE: The features are updated fine when i use QGIS 2.14.3).

Commit errors:
              ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added.

```
          Provider errors:
              WFS service exception:
                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@11805eee
            java.lang.ClassCastException@11805eee
```

I am using Geoserver 2.9.0, PostGIS 2.2, and QGIS 2.16.3

Geoserver log
[image]

Comment: can you check the GeoServer log and see what it says there

Comment: Geoserver log is clean

Comment: turn logging up then, it must be there as it's a java error that QGis is reporting